# why my check box length is not correct? in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

i am using laravel bootstrap where check box is geting by foreach loop
html

```
<div id="y"></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="confirm-to[]" value="{{ $order->id }}" class="approve-to z" onclick="updateCount()"/>
```

javascript

```
    window.updateCount = function() {
    var x = ($(".z:checked").length);
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = x;
    
};
```

problem is that when i click to check box it find length with +1 means if i checked 1 box then its value to div id y = 2 whats wrong in it?

Comment: It’s probably the use of the `click` event that is what is wrong here, use the `change` event instead.

Comment: (And using “old-school” event handling applied by `onxyz` HTML attributes, when jQuery is already in use, is quite yucky.)